# After succesfully installing tesseract_ocr in Ubuntu it shows no mudule named tesseract_ocr

Tags: ocr, pycharm, tesseract, python-tesseract

I installed Tesseract OCR through Linux terminal, but when I tried to import it in Python, the error appeared:

> /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/web/Documents/pnt/ocr.py
>   
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   
> File "/home/web/Documents/pnt/ocr.py", line 1, in 
>   
> import tesseract
>   
> ImportError: No module named tesseract

Answer (score 0):

To check if you properly installed tesseract-ocr on the system. First try entering into your command line:

```
tesseract
```

and/or

```
whereis tesseract-ocr
```

Now for the next step you need a wrapper for tesserect, such as [pytesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract) or [python-tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/), to import and use the ocr in python.